# I'm trying to declare a variable as the same value of a MySql data, and a counter for the number of columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I'm using, it connects to the database and then the 'Q' option in the textbox shows a table, the 'I' option should INSERT a value in a table named "ventas" (sells) with the same name as is in "articulos" (articles) where has the same "codigo" (code) and count the number of columns in "ventas" for the "codigo" there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="query.php" method="post">
<p align="center">
<textarea name="instrucciones" cols="70" rows="20">
<?php if (isset($_POST['procesar'])){
  $codigo=$_POST['instrucciones'];
  if (substr($codigo,0,1)=="Q"){
   require_once('configsub.php');
   $link=mysql_connect("sql202.byetcluster.com", $username, $password);
   mysql_select_db($database, $link);
   if (substr($codigo,2,1)=="A") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY nombre";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
     echo $myrow['codigo']." ".$myrow['nombre']."\n";
    }
   }
   if (substr($codigo,2,1)=="M") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM monedas ORDER BY simbolo";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
     echo $myrow['simbolo']." ".$myrow['moneda']." ".$myrow['pais']." ".$myrow['valormxn']."\n";
    }
   }
   if (substr($codigo,2,1)=="U") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY tag";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
     echo $myrow['tag']." ".$myrow['mail']." ".$myrow['cp']." ".$myrow['direccion']."\n";
    }
   }
   if (substr($codigo,2,1)=="V") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vendedores ORDER BY tag";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
     echo $myrow['tag']." ".$myrow['mail']." ".$myrow['nombre']." ".$myrow['direccion']." ".$myrow['cuentabancaria']."\n";
    }
   }
  }
  else if (substr($codigo,0,1)=="I"){
   $articulo=substr($codigo,2);
   $articulo=substr($articulo,0,strpos($articulo," "));
   $precio=substr($codigo,3);
   $precio=substr($precio,0,strpos($precio," "));
   require_once('configsub.php');
   $link=mysql_connect("sql202.byetcluster.com", $username, $password);
   mysql_select_db($database, $link);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE codigo='$articulo'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
   if (mysql_affected_rows()==0){
    echo "El c&oacutedigo del ARTICULO no existe, indique otro";
   }
   else {
    $nombre =  mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM articulos WHERE codigo = '$articulo'");
    $resultnom = mysql_fetch_array($nombre);
    
    $resultcod = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from ventas");
    $codigo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultcod);
    
    $sqlin="INSERT INTO ventas (codigo, nombre, precio) ";
    $sqlin= $sqlin."VALUES (\"$codigo['total']\", \"resultnom['nombre']\", \"$precio\")";
    
    $resultin = mysql_query($sqlin,$link);
     
    echo "Registro para dar de alta"; 
   }
  }
  else {
   echo "\t Ayuda \n";
   echo "=============================================\n";
   echo " Q <tabla> Mostrar registros de <tabla>\n";
   echo "I  <articulo><precio>\n";
  }
 }

?>
</textarea>
</p>
<p align="center">
<input name="procesar" type="submit" value="Procesar" />
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: This `(\"$codigo['total']\", \"resultnom['nombre']\"` will definitely not produce the result you're expecting. Do you have error reporting on? Check your servers error log. However, this would be an anti-issue if you use parameterized prepared statements instead (since you wouldn't need to concatenate the query at all).